# Скромный и скоромный

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Как мы знаем, скоромное блюдо - это не постное, то есть, содержащее продукты животного происхождения. А еще есть слово "скромный", которое отличается всего на одну гласную.
И вот интересно: эти слова как-то родственны или просто созвучны?
Извините, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, просто созвучны. См.:

**СКОРОМНЫЙ** Искон. Суф. производное от *скоромъ* «жир, масло». **Общеслав.** *skormъ (откуда* скоромъ *в результате появления полногласия) того же корня, что и* корм* «жир, корм».
http://etymological.academic.ru/4721

**СКРОМНЫЙ** Заимств. в XVII в. **из польск. яз.**, где *skromny* — суф. производное на базе предлога s «с» и сущ. *kroma* «граница» (в тв. п.). *Скромный* буквально — «тот, кто держится в рамках, ограниченный».
http://etymological.academic.ru/4730